# Weird error when trying to optimize my game in Pygame

Tags: python, performance, optimization, pygame

So I'm making a game in Pygame and I made a system that spawns a bunch of trees and rocks. These are objects that call an `update()` function where some necessary calculations for their position are made and they get blited to the screen. I'm trying to make a program that only really updates a foliage object when its visible on the screen, So I made a function that returns if its onscreen.

So I added an *if* statement that runs this function and suddenly I get 600 FPS average but for some reason the player is moving very slowly and the animation goes very fast. I use a delta time system which might have something to do with it but I'm not certain.

Here is the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/RaptoRRmakesGames/survivorinio):

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint, choice
import time

screen_width = 800#int(1500/1.5)
screen_height = 800#int(1500/1.5)

flags =  HWSURFACE|DOUBLEBUF|NOFRAME   #| FULLSCREEN

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height), flags, 1000000000)

fps = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
last_time = time.time()
time_now = last_time
dt = 0

images = {
    "players" : {
        "base_right" : [
            pygame.image.load("images/player/baseplr1.png").convert_alpha(),
            pygame.image.load("images/player/baseplr2.png").convert_alpha(),
            ],
        "base_left" : [
            pygame.transform.flip(pygame.image.load("images/player/baseplr1.png").convert_alpha(),True, False),
            pygame.transform.flip(pygame.image.load("images/player/baseplr2.png").convert_alpha(),True, False),
            ],
    },
    "enemies" : {
        "simple" : [
            pygame.image.load("images/enemies/zombie.png").convert_alpha()
        ]
    },
    "foliage" : {
        "tree" : pygame.image.load("images/foliage/tree.png").convert_alpha() ,
        "rock" : pygame.image.load("images/foliage/rock.png").convert_alpha() ,
    },

    "background" : pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("background.png").convert_alpha(),(1000,1000)),

}

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, stats, skin, ori):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.dmg = stats[0]
        self.hp = stats[1]
        self.speed = stats[2]

        self.skin = skin

        self.ori = ori
        self.index_max = len(images["players"][self.skin+"_"+self.ori])
        self.index = 0
        self.image = images["players"][self.skin+"_"+self.ori][self.index]

        self.count = False
        self.timer = 0
        self.anim_max = 16

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos)

        self.x, self.y = self.rect.x, self.rect.y

    def update(self):
        self.movement()
        self.animate()

    def movement(self):
        self.keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        self.count = False

        if self.keys[K_d]:
            self.x += self.speed * dt
            self.ori = "right"
            self.count = True
        if self.keys[K_a]:
            self.x -= self.speed * dt
            self.ori = "left"
            self.count = True

        if self.keys[K_s]:
            self.y += self.speed* dt
            self.count = True
        if self.keys[K_w]:
            self.y -= self.speed * dt
            self.count = True

        self.rect.x = self.x - main_cam.scroll[0]
        self.rect.y = self.y - main_cam.scroll[1]

    def animate(self):
        if self.count:
            self.timer += 1

            if self.timer >= self.anim_max:
                self.timer = 0
                self.index += 1
                if self.index == self.index_max:
                    self.index = 0

        self.image = images["players"][self.skin+"_"+self.ori][self.index]

class Foliage:
    def __init__(self, pos, type):
        self.image = images["foliage"][type]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = pos[0]
        self.y = pos[1]
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x = self.x - main_cam.scroll[0]
        self.rect.y = self.y - main_cam.scroll[1]
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x,self.rect.y))

    def on_screen(self):
        return self.rect.x > 0 and self.rect.x < screen_width and self.rect.y > 0 and self.rect.y < screen_width

class Camera:
    def __init__(self, speed):
        self.scroll = [5,5]
        self.speed = speed
    def move_on_command(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[K_UP]:
            self.scroll[1] -= self.speed * dt
        if keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.scroll[1] += self.speed * dt
        if keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.scroll[0] += self.speed * dt
        if keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.scroll[0] -= self.speed * dt

    def follow(self, obj, speed=12):

        if (obj.x - self.scroll[0]) != screen.get_width()/2:
            self.scroll[0] += ((obj.x - (self.scroll[0] + screen.get_width()/2))/speed ) * dt
        if obj.y - self.scroll[1] != screen.get_height()/2:
            self.scroll[1] += ((obj.y - (self.scroll[1] + screen.get_height()/2))/speed) * dt

class Folliage_Manager:
    def __init__(self, multi=1):
        self.foliage = []
        self.foliage_amount = multi

    def spawn_foliage(self, amount):
        for i in range(int(amount*self.foliage_amount)):
            cord = (randint(-10000,10000), randint(-10000, 100000))
            e = randint(0,6)
            if e > 4:
                newfol = Foliage(cord, choice(["tree", "rock"]))
                self.foliage.append(newfol)

# Instantiation of stuff
main_cam = Camera(1)

playerGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()

player = Player((500,500), [25, 100, 2], "base", "right")
playerGroup.add(player)

fm = Folliage_Manager(multi=0.8)
fm.spawn_foliage(30000)

# settings

def get_dt():
    global last_time
    dt = 0
    time_now = time.time()
    dt = time_now - last_time
    last_time = time_now
    return dt * 300

left_border = -10000
right_border = 10000
top_border = -10000
bottom_border = 10000

def spawnBackground(res):
    global left_border, top_border, right_border, bottom_border

    for i in range(int(-1000*res/2),int(1000*res/2), 1000):
        for x in range(int(-1000*res/2),int(1000*res/2), 1000):
            screen.blit(images["background"], (main_cam.scroll[0]*-1 + i, main_cam.scroll[1]*-1 +x))
        #print(i)


def render(groups):
    spawnBackground(10)
    main_cam.follow(player, 60)

    for fol in fm.foliage:
        #if fol.rect.x > 0 and fol.rect.x < screen_width and fol.rect.y >0 and fol.rect.y > screen_height:
        if fol.on_screen():
            fol.update()
        #print("PRINTING R")

    for group in groups:
        group.update()
        group.draw(screen)

    screen.blit(images["enemies"]["simple"][0], (500-main_cam.scroll[0],300-main_cam.scroll[1]))

pygame.event.set_allowed([QUIT,KEYDOWN])

fpse = []

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    dt = int(get_dt())

    render([playerGroup])

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            run = False

    fpse.append(int(clock.get_fps()))

    pygame.display.update()

print(f"""
MAX FPS:     {max(fpse)}
LEAST FPS:   {min(fpse)}
AVERAGE FPS: {int(sum(fpse)/len(fpse))}
""")

quit()
```

Comment: Your foliage is generated over an area 20000x110000, whereas your window is 800x800 so it's not surprising that skipping the `blit()` on all of those outside the window gave a good speedup.  Maybe you meant the `y` region to be -10000 to 10000, not to 100000.

Comment: yes thanks for noticing my typo it actually saved me like 30 minutes of keyboard-head banging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that your code is using `time.time()` which has a granularity of decimal seconds.  It is multiplied by 300, but this looks like a fudge to speed it up??

It's better to use the PyGame [function](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) `pygame.time.get_ticks()` for all in-game times.  This function returns the number of milliseconds since your program started.  So changing your `get_dt()`:

```
def get_dt():
    global last_time
    dt = 0
    time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()  # milliseconds since game start
    dt = time_now - last_time
    last_time = time_now
    #return dt * 300
    return dt
```

Makes the player move more quickly, and it fixes the occasional weird slowdowns I was seeing - maybe this is a rounding of the fractional seconds from `time.time()`?  (I did not investigate why.)

You player animation uses simple "counter" based frame control.  This means the speed of animation is directly tied to the on-screen frame-rate.  It might work out better if this animation rate is tied to the PyGame clock.

The approach taken is to store the time of the *next* frame change.  Then the code looks at the current time, comparing it with the future-time.  If that time is *now*, the animation frame is changed, and the future-time recalculated.  I also changed `Player.count` to `Player.animating` (boolean).

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos, stats, skin, ori):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        # [...]
 
        self.ANIMATION_RATE = 50   # milliseconds between animation updates
        self.animating = False     # is the animation running (replaces self.count)
        # Future time of next animation frame
        self.next_anim_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() + self.ANIMATION_RATE

    def movement(self):
        self.keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        self.animating = False

        if self.keys[K_d]:
            self.x += self.speed * dt
            self.ori = "right"
            self.animating = True

        # [...]  Rest of identical changes omitted for the sake of brevity


    def animate(self):
        if ( self.animating ):
            time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            # Is it time to do change the animation frame
            if ( time_now > self.next_anim_time ):
                self.next_anim_time = time_now + self.ANIMATION_RATE  # set time for next frame
                self.index += 1
                if ( self.index >= self.index_max ):
                    self.index = 0
                self.image = images["players"][self.skin+"_"+self.ori][self.index]
```

Note also that the animation function was changing the image every time (mostly back to the same thing), rather than when a change was actually needed.

Oh, and I never saw anything like a rock or leaf in testing.  Maybe there's a further issue here, or they're meant to be rare items.

Comment: yeah no the reason u didnt see trees or rocks is because i accidentally put an extra zero in the `spawn_foliage` function of the `Folliage_Manager` class. So they all just spawned very far down

edit: No ur right for some reason the never actually render

edit 2: I  made the check happen inside of each individual tree/rock and it works pretty much, but not a great fps boost

Comment: hey also for some reason the character is moving extremely fast, the speed on the object is 2 (really slow) and the dt looks normal can you help me?

Comment: @RaptoRR - "Fast", "Slow" aren't good descriptions of what you desire.  Can you be more precise?  How long should it take to move a screen-width away from Mr Zombie?  One second? Two?  Half a second?

Comment: it should take atleast 30 seconds to go from topleft side of map to the bottomright side

Comment: @RaptoRR In this case I would change your player speed to be a decimal.  The moment functions need to convert to integer during update: `self.x -= int( self.speed * dt )`.  With that change, and then changing the player speed to `0.25` it moves much more slowly.  If you still want to keep a speed factor of say 1..10, just multiply Player.speed by 0.25 in the `Player.__init__()`.

Comment: i know im kinda bombing you with questions but, my player isnt actually in the middle of the screen when still. He is a little bit to the bottom right. I kinda know why this happens but i cannot find the variable i need to tweak to fix it. The code for the moving of the camera is at the `Camera` class on the `follow()` function

Comment: @RaptoRR - I *think* it's the `obj.x` and `.y` in the camera follow.  Also you don't start the player centre-window.